# Flutter navigate between Dart files

Tags: flutter, dart

hello I am trying to make a flutter program but the program is very slow because I am making all in the same widget someone knows how to use po Navigator to change from Dart file

Answer (score 1):

First dart file:

```
class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Open route'),
          onPressed: () {
           Navigator.push(
           context,
           MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
          );},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Second dart file:

```
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```